# How to set a default application to open a file in mac?

Tags: finder, applications, textedit

In a mac (10.14.6) I want to set the default application to files of type  'err' (i.e. files like `test.err` or `output.err`) to be `TextEdit`.

For that I follow the description given [here](https://www.imore.com/how-set-mac-app-default-when-opening-file), and set the default application to be `TextEdit`.

[image]

However, when I double click on that exact same file in the finder, I see the following text box:

[image]

So what am I missing? Why does it nor work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the existing two methods are not working - they both should.

Alternatively try [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) which as far as I'm aware still works in Catalina. [I can only test up to Mojave.]

I added this manually using the + button & it actually suggested TextEdit itself. I'd suggest also checking 'Override file creator' & see if that might help.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**The simple process goes as:**

Right click on .err file and press <kbd>Option</kbd> , then **Open with** will change to **Always open with**.

Then select the appropriate application you want to open. It will open and then close it. 
Test it by double-clicking and then it should work without any issue.

**Reference for it as a screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks - so the page I found is incorrect. I see

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it? If then would you be kind to accept the answer too :)

Comment: No it still does not work. When I download a different 'err' file, the mac asks me again

Comment: It does not work. Sometimes it does. Strange behavior. But well, its a mac.

Comment: Maybe when I open the exact same file it does work, but if I select a different file with an '.err' ending, I am asked again. But not sure

Comment: This answer sets the default only for **one** file.  For all `*.err` files you should click "Change All" after doing "Get Info" as in the question.  That works for me on Mojave - not sure why it doesn't work for OP...

Comment: The "Change All" button within "Get info" is greyed out.I cannot click on "Change All". I tried to also use all combination of the Option key, Shift, Ctrl, but this does not change anything